# Jhipster 5.7 microservice failed to start on windows with error CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long

Tags: jhipster

Jhipster 5.7  microservice failed to start on windows with error  CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long

I have created a Jhipster micro service. when I am trying to start, I get error   CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long.
All other questions are suggesting to reduce classpath or usning IntelliJ. None of them explained how. Here are few things I have trying:

1. Remove Unnecessary jar from classpath:

   - I have fresh Jhipsterap. I don't know which jar I can remove 
     without breaking it.
2. Use IntelliJ

   - I am running the service from command line.
3. Move your project or maven repo to "c:" drive to make path short.

   - I can't. The repo is huge and is being shared.

Let me know if there is any other solution for this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is fairly simple way of reducing classpath on windows, if you can not move your local repo. Here is how:

Open command prompt and execute this command

```
mklink /J c:\repo C:\<long path to your maven repository>
```

This will create  a link to your maven repository. Now run the service like this:

```
mvn -Dmaven.repo.local=c:\repo spring-boot:run
```

Thats all. Now your classpath will be reduced by around 10000 characters (tried for jhipster gateway app).

Good luck.

Comment: Worked like charm!! you saved my day, I was looking to sole this for a long time :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: I tried many, many things and this is the only that worked. Also for powershell users:
`cd \ ` then `new-item -itemtype symboliclink -path  -name m2repo -value <long-path-to-maven-repo>`

Comment: what helped me it was running the cmd as administrator :)

Answer (score 1):

[Forking](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/run-mojo.html#fork) is enabled by default since Spring Boot 2.2. 
See [Since 2.2.0 spring-boot-maven-plugin create 2 java process (may cause CreateProcess error=206). Need workaround to fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61125404/since-2-2-0-spring-boot-maven-plugin-create-2-java-process-may-cause-createproc) question and solution

Comment: Disabling forking will disable some features such as an agent, custom JVM arguments, devtools or specifying the working directory to use. But thanks for finding this this option.