# How add a firebase dependency in java using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, firebase, jhipster, firebase-admin

I want to add the firebase dependency on a java project of jhipster, I'm using eclipse, but when I add this dependency:

```
   <dependency>
     <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
     <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
     <version>6.8.1</version>
   </dependency>
```

that give Firebase, I get this error in my app in Java in eclipse:

[image]

The error 206 in english is:

```
the filename or extension is too long
```

I appreciate much your help

Comment: Please don't show pictures of code and text on Stack Overflow.  It's always better to copy all the relevant text into the question itself so it's easier to read and search.

Comment: Classical issue on Windows, you can find many answers on stackoverflow. Like this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54246648/jhipster-5-7-microservice-failed-to-start-on-windows-with-error-createprocess-er

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jhipster 5.7 microservice failed to start on windows with error CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54246648/jhipster-5-7-microservice-failed-to-start-on-windows-with-error-createprocess-er)